# Getting parentheses from a list of chars

Tags: scala, recursion

I wanted to implement a function to retrieve all parentheses from a given list of chars

```
def getParentheses(chars: List[Char]): String = {
    if (chars.isEmpty) ""
    else {
      val head = chars.head.toString
      if (head == "(" || head == ")") head + getParentheses(chars.tail)
    }
  }
```

but I keep  getting an error from the Scala IDE on the fifth line about a type mismatch but the line looks fine to me

`if (head == "(" || head == ")") head + getParentheses(chars.tail)`

So how can I fix it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is stating that `getParentheses` expects a `String` as return value but your function returns `Unit`. The last line in a Scala function is the return value which in your case is an `if` which returns `Unit`. You would have to refactor the second `if`. Here's how I would do it with pattern matching.

```
def getParentheses(chars: List[Char]): String = chars match {
  case h::t if h == '(' || h == ')' => h + getParentheses(t)
  case h::t => getParentheses(t)
  case Nil => ""
}
```

It's probably more idiomatic to do it with `filter` though.

```
scala> List(')', 'a', ')').filter(x => x == ')' || x == '(') 
res0: List[Char] = List(), ))
```

Comment: That filter method fixes the problem in one line actually, I like it! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make use of List.collect function that takes PartialFunction:

```
val isParentheses: PartialFunction[Char, Char] = { 
  case ch: Char if(ch == '(' || ch == ')' ) => ch  
}
val onlyParentheses = listOfchars.collect(isParentheses)
```

Note I have not tested this solution although it should work.

EDIT.

Sorry I haven't noticed you want your code fixed. I think the problem lies in part

`head + getParentheses`

your function returns String and head is Char. Are you sure you can concatenate Char to String using `+` ?

Comment: but doesn't this line convert the first element of the list into a char?
  `val head = chars.head.toString`

Comment: @Brian was right. The second `if` is not exhaustive. What happens if this part `head == "(" || head == ")"` evaluates to false? then your method doesn't return anything. In other words it returns `Unit` when you wrote that it returns String.

Comment: Ok now I get it, when a function is supposed to return something, it should return at all costs. So here a simple `else` fixes my problem, but @Brian solution is more concise and gets the job done in one line by using the filter method.